# Access Error: Site or Page Not Found. Cannot open URL

Tags: apache, xampp

Здравствуйте!

Хотел хостить сайт со своей машины с помощью xampp. Апач запустился без проблем на 80 и 443 портах. С локального адреса (127.0.0.1/index.php) сайт просматривается замечательно, но при попытке просмотреть сайт с использованием моего IP или no-ip домена (primer.no-ip.biz/index.php), что по сути одинаково , браузер (вроде даже сам Апач) оповещает, что страницу найти не удаётся. Ошибка звучит так:

> Access Error: Site or Page Not Found. Cannot open URL.

Использую XAMPP 1.6.8. IP у меня белый, но динамичный. Такая же ошибка, если пытаются зайти другие люди. Подскажите, в чём проблема? Самостоятельно решить не получается, уже второй день сижу с этим. Спасибо огромное тому, кто сможет таки помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Порты 80 и 443 для 2.60.213.48 закрыты. Проверил сервисом [ping.eu](http://ping.eu)

Comment: У меня уже давно другой IP, картинку заливал ещё вчера. Порты я и сам проверял, они отрыты иначе apache бы не запустился.

Comment: Вообще закажи выделенный IP и все. Смотри, у меня сейчас адрес 91.124.99.139, а порт 80 закрыт из "внешнего мира".

Comment: Нет на это ни желания, ни финансов. Прошу всётаки искать решение при данных условиях.

Comment: Так сумма вообще смешная, в частности украинский оператор Укртелеком берет порядка 5$ в месяц.

Answer (score 1):

скорее всего, внешний *ip*-адрес присвоен не сетевому интерфейсу на вашей машине, а какому-то шлюзу (у провайдера или у вас — роутер, модем и т.п.).

соответственно, на этом шлюзе и следует настраивать проброс 80-го порта на вашу машину.